# Why would an ASP.NET page be empty, but for a user control (.ascx)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was hired to do some maintenance to a web site, and I found that there is a user control (.ascx) for every page (.aspx) and only one, like a one-to-one, and every .aspx is empty except for the user control. I dont see the use of that, because every user control is the entire page. Is there a benefit for doing that, or is it useless? I'm afraid to say is something useless becouse I dont have much experience.

Comment: That seems like an awful design to me as well.

Comment: UserControls are more flexible than pages. So you might want to put multiple of them into one page or add them dynmically to one page or add them to an ASP.NET Ajax TabContainer into different TabPanels.

Comment: There is probably some reason it's like that, just probably not a good one. Don't be afraid to ask about it. Most people would rather you ask questions so you understand how the site works.

Comment: Unless the controls are reused or these are some pages with multiple controls, +1 for useless!

Comment: I have *many* ASCX files for just a few ASPX files (and a WebPart) ;-) There is nothing inherently wrong with this approach and the plumbing / total code in the end will be about the same. There are some slight differences between a Page and UserControl, but nothing to fear either way ..

Comment: This sounds like something for The Daily WTF (http://thedailywtf.com/)!

Comment: @GarrettVlieger Why? What inherent "WTF" is there? It sounds like the ASPX files are just proxies (for the most part), but what is inherently wrong with that?

Comment: @pst, if you've ever seen the code submitted on there, you'll know what I mean. Just bad patterns and programmers that over-architect things because they don't know what they're doing.

Comment: @GarrettVlieger: no, not at all, see my answer!!!!

Comment: There's nothing wrong in using UserControls as proxies for pages as @pst has noted. Reusability is not the only purpose of UserControls.

Comment: I'm not doubting the usefulness of user controls. I use them fairly regularly. I just feel that in the case presented -- having a one-to-one relationship between ASPX pages and ASCX controls -- provides no real value. It just makes it a headache for people maintaining the site (like the person asking the question).

Comment: @GarrettVlieger: no, you're not getting it, read my answer!! It's super useful to have a control per page: when you debug the development page you're not loading all the other controls that are on the single-page version of the site.

Comment: @Frenchie, I get what you're saying, and I see that you have this special case for development and debugging. If the person asking the question said that they had this exact scenario, I would maybe see the value, but he said that it's just one-to-one and nothing more. That's not useful in my experience and just adds more complexity for no added value (in this case).

Comment: There's always more to that than this :)

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you, my scenario is just ont to one as Garret said. and thanks for the tip for debugginng and developtment.Now im sure of what i was thinking, it is really appreciated your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UserControl is useful as it can be used in many places throughout the application. If its only specific to one page, the user-control loses its purpose.

User-Controls are supposed to be modular and supposed to be designed that they can easily be used in other pages.

From the sounds of the application your maintaining, you'll have to see if the user control is unique to the page, or if its the same user control is used through the app and decide to move things.

Answer (score 3):

**My site is built like this: I have several .ascx files and several .aspx files that contain just one user control.**

Now there's also a special `.aspx` file that's actually **a single-page application** on which I register every `.ascx` control. The reason I have `.aspx` files for both the single-page application and for each separate "page" is that during development, I'm mostly working on one "page" at a time so I don't need to load all the other modules of the application. By keeping each module in a separate `.ascx` file I can make changes to a module and the changes will seamlessly affect **both** the single-page version of the site as well as the `.aspx` page I use for development purposes.

Hope this helps.